# rewrite rule for home/index page

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I've been struggling for a while already and all of my attempts failed so I have no other choice but to ask for help here...

a) I've made a custom post type `page_blox` whose `capability_type => 'page'` and `rewrite => array( 'slug' => 'blox' )`

b) All of `page_blox` pages can be selected on **Reading Settings** screen (Admin) as 'Front page displays' > Static page

So far so good. However...

**The problem:**

Front-end home page URL doesn't read **my_domain.com** any more but also appends `post_type` and page slug so it looks like
**my_domain.com?page_blox=my-page-slug**

**The Question:**

I believe it has something to do with WP's rewrite rules so how do I remove that appendix (`?page_blox=my-page-slug`) from home page URL?

My initial code did not score any results. Is there anybody willing to tell what's wrong with it?

```
function k_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $frontPost = get_post( get_option( 'page_on_front' ) );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array( '^$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?' . $frontPost->post_type . '=' . $frontPost->post_name ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'k_rewrite_rules' );
```

Comment: I am not English native speaker... But I thougth I know language quite well. But I have no idea what you tring to do. Can you step by step say what you achive to do with your homepage and what you basiclly did...

Comment: Did you re-save your Permalink settings to flush the rewrite rules?

Comment: Yeap, permalinks resaved whenever changes are made. And when I `var_dump( $wp_rewrite )` new rule is not there.